# Hacer res.redirect desde getServerSideProps en NextJS

Tags: backend, redirección, next.js

Al entrar en la pagina de login ("/login") estoy tratando de comprobar si el usuario está correctamente autentificado, en ese caso quiero redirigirlo a la pagina principal ("/"). De lo contrario, si su web token es incorrecto o ha expirado, borro la cookie que contiene dicho token y no hago nada mas y por lo tanto entra a la pagina de login. Estoy usando getServerSideProps con este proposito, no porque necesite props desde el backend (por ahora)

Al probar el código, cuando me autentifico correctamente se redirige automaticamente a la pagina principal ("/"), luego yo fuerzo volver al login con la url y veo que se ejecuta la instrucción res.redirect("/") pero no hace nada, se queda en el login.

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res }) {
    debugger
    const AuthToken = req.cookies.AuthToken
    if (AuthToken) {
        try {
            //Verificamos su token, si es valido y vigente no arrojará error
            await jwtVerify(AuthToken, new TextEncoder().encode(tokenSecret))
            res.redirect("/") //Esta es la linea que parece ignorar...
        } catch (err) {
            //Si el token está caducado o es invalido...
            //Elimino la cookie que lo contiene y no hago nada mas por lo que entra en /login
            const cookie = serialize("AuthToken", "x", { maxAge: 0 })
            res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", cookie)
            console.log(err.name)
        }
    }

    return {
        props: {},
    }
}
```

En la documentación de NextJS he leído esto...

> res.redirect([status,] path) - Redirects to a specified path or URL.
> status must be a valid HTTP status code. If not specified, status
> defaults to "307" "Temporary redirect".

...por lo que también he probado con lo siguiente (sin éxito):

```
res.redirect(200, "/")
res.status(200).redirect("/")
```

Me da un error que indica que res.redirect no es una función.
¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Mil gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que la parte de la documentación que leíste es para las [`API Routes`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/response-helpers). Si ves la documentación de [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#redirect), lo que te recomiendan es retornar un `objeto redirect` de la siguiente manera:

```js
export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res }) {
    debugger
    const AuthToken = req.cookies.AuthToken
    if (AuthToken) {
        try {
            //Verificamos su token, si es valido y vigente no arrojará error
            await jwtVerify(AuthToken, new TextEncoder().encode(tokenSecret))
            
            // Así debes redireccionar 
            return {
                  redirect: {
                  destination: '/',
                  permanent: false,
               },
             }

        } catch (err) {
            //Si el token está caducado o es invalido...
            //Elimino la cookie que lo contiene y no hago nada mas por lo que entra en /login
            const cookie = serialize("AuthToken", "x", { maxAge: 0 })
            res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", cookie)
            console.log(err.name)
        }
    }

    return {
        props: {},
    }
}
```